# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler skips onSuccess function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to fill a select element in my HTML file with data from the spreadsheet which the script is bound to.

So far, I have the code below for newDeal.html. The empty select element (id="contactname") is the one that i need to fill with data returned from arr_customers() function:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body onload="onload()">
    <p>Contact name:</p>
    <select id="contactname" autocorrect="on" autocomplete="on">
    </select>
  </body>
  <script>
         var vals;
         function placeCustomers(values) {
            var select = document.getElementById("contactname");
            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                Logger.log(i);
                var opt = values[i];
                var el = document.createElement('option');
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }
          }
          function onload() {
            placeCustomers(vals);
          }
          function onSuccess(values) {
            vals = values;
          }
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).arr_customers();
  </script>
</html>
```

By the server-side, i have the arr_customers function, which returns selected items from the sheet 'Customers List'. The function works fine when running alone, and returns an array with names (Like: ['Bruno','Neymar']):

```
function arr_customers() {
      var tbl = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my-spreadsheet-id').getSheetByName('Customers List').getDataRange().getValues();
      var return_array = [];
      for (var i = 1; i < tbl.length; i++) {
        if (tbl[i][6] == 'C') { // condition needed for customer to go to list    
            return_array.push(tbl[i][1]);
        }
      }
      return return_array;
    }
```

And at last, the code for the custom menu to open the modal dialog:

```
function uiBuilder() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Project')
    .addItem('Create new project...', 'newProject')
   .addToUi();
}
function newProject() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('newDeal');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'New Project');
}
```

The problem is that the onSuccess function is not running after arr_customer has returned a value. I used some Logs to discover this. I've even commented all unnecessary code and tried to run it through Spreadhseets UI with a single line "Logger.log('test')" within onSuccess function, and nothing showed up into the log.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? I've seen Google documentation, it says the withSuccessHandler:

> Sets a callback function to run if the server-side function returns
>   successfully. The server's return value is passed to the function as
>   the first argument, and the user object (if any) is passed as a second
>   argument.

Maybe i'm missing something, if anyone have any clue, please share :)

Comment: When is the `google.script.run` line supposed to execute? You don't have it in a function.

Comment: It executes when the user opens the HTML. I already checked, and the arr_customer function successully runs when the window pops up.

Comment: Another thing: i also tried using withFailureHandler, and the callback function isnt reached again

Comment: As described in documentation, the failure handler for a `google.script.run` async task is only called if the server function throws an unhandled exception. If the server function exits by any other means, its output (from `return < something >`, otherwise `undefined`) is passed to the task's success handler. **PS your written `onSuccess` function merely sets a variable in your client code - it never tells any other function in your client code to do anything with that variable's new value.**

Comment: I get your point. The function `arr_customers` returns values successfully, and the `onSuccess` functions doesn't run (removed all code and used Log to check). About your PS: `onSuccess` writes values on the variable, then please note the action `onload` within the `<body>` element. It should run the function `placeCustomers` with the values on the variable. Anyway, in my first code I was calling `placeCustomers` inside `onSuccess`... this was just an experimentation to work this around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Here is the final code for newDeal.html which worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload='updateCustomers()'>
    <p>Nome do Contato:</p>
    <select id="slContato" name="Contato" autocorrect="on" autocomplete="on">
    </select>
  </body>
  <script>
          function placeCustomers(values) {
            var select = document.getElementById("slContato");
            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                var opt = values[i];
                var el = document.createElement("OPTION");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }
          }

          function updateCustomers() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(placeCustomers).arr_clientes();
          }
  </script>
</html>
```

It seems somehow this was a problem with `Logger.log()`. After I removed all Log lines from the HTML code, it worked!

Comment: `Logger` is an Apps Script class - it is not a function available to your browser. Logging in the browser is done via `console.log`, and sends output to the browser console.

Comment: Great! I'm quite new on HTML and this `console.log` is going to be really helpful, thank you very much for your attention :)